# Using SlickGrid (v5.x) with Svelte (or Sveltekit)

Tags: svelte, slickgrid

I was wondering if anybody has managed to integrate SlickGrid (the latest Typescript version) with Svelte? I can see that people are using it with React and Angular, but can find no info on Svelte. I just tried to import it myself (tried both npm, and as a script reference to cdn), but have come up against errors that even Copilot can't help me resolve.  I've been using a much older version of SlickGrid for over 10+ years in another project.

Comment: I'm one of the maintainers, but I'm afraid I use the vanilla js/ts version, not really being a fan of these front end frameworks. @Ghiscoding   is the maintainer of the React and Angular versions, he may be able to assist. It would be helpful to give us a sample of the error you're getting, even if just to give the flavour of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, @BenMcIntyre. The errors had to do with what Svelte felt were various missing exports. After writing my original question, I did stumble upon the work of Ghiscoding which looks very promising (though not yet for Svelte). If I knew a bit more about what I'm doing, I'd try my hand at adapting slickgrid-universal to Svelte, but it's probably a bit beyond me, as I'm pretty new to Svelte.

Comment: I've never used Svelte, so I can't help with that. However all the ports I maintain are just simple Component with simple imports of SlickGrid. You should be able to import it in Svelte like any other JS libraries especially now that it's written in TypeScript. I recommend using the ESM import to do that (there are 3 build types, the ESM is really the one you'll need)

Comment: Thanks @ghiscoding, I'll give it another try tomorrow using the ESM build.

Comment: It worked!  Well, apart from styling.   But the grid has made an appearance, albeit without style (and therefore jumbled).

Comment: @ghiscoding, I have to admit defeat on getting styling to work.  I'm lost in a sea of directories. I have looked at the examples and how they do it, but something's not going right for me. The style sheets are loading (no errors, and the Network tab proves it), but no matter what, all the column headers and rows are bunched up in a vertical column on the left of the grid div.  Moreover, none of the slickgrid styles are actually appearing in the element inspector. I must be missing a step somewhere...

Comment: I'm not sure why you keep asking me since this is definitely a Svelte question, which again I have never ever used. Perhaps try to add the Alpine Theme to your `index.html`, that usually works!? I added the Alpine Theme CDN link to the project today `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slickgrid@5.8.1/dist/styles/css/slick-alpine-theme.min.css">` . Also note that the CSS is not part of the exported JS file, it should be loaded separately via proper CSS style import

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, didn't mean to latch onto you :-). I'm pretty sure this is not longer a svelte question, as the grid's imported properly; it's just the styling I'm confused about. But you're right... we've moved past the original reason for this post. Thanks for your suggestion - I'll give Alpine theme a go. I'm sure I can nut this out from here.

Comment: FWIW, @ghiscoding your suggestion about Alpine theme was spot-on, and fixed everything :-)

Comment: I would suggest you write all the steps in an answer below and accept your own answer since I'm sure this can help others who wish to try it in Svelte just like you.